# Python JSON Ensure Encoding

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I create a JSON file with special characters as strings.

I create for example a dict with

```
dict[u"Züge"] = ...
json.dump(dict, file)
```

When i view the dumped file it looks like this:

```
{
  "Z\u00fcge": [
    {
```

Is there a way to write to the file the encoding so that any text editor will automatically display the right characters?

i then get the following error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xfc' in
>   position 2: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: yes but how to overcome the error is not mentioned there :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `ensure_ascii=False` in your `json.dump` function :

```
dict[u"Züge"] = ...
json.dump(dict, file,ensure_ascii=False)
```

[Character Encodings in Json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html):

> As permitted, though not required, by the RFC, this module’s serializer sets ensure_ascii=True by default, thus escaping the output so that the resulting strings only contain ASCII characters.

Answer (score 0):

Specify `ensure_ascii=False` when calling [`json.dump`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/json.html#json.dump):

```
json.dump(dict, file, ensure_ascii=False)
```